# @InjectAll annotation to mark multiple fields as @Inject

Tags: cdi

I often find huge list of @Inject fields at the beginning of a class. This is a lot of redundant repetitions of the @Inject annotation.

Using some custom annotation magic, is it possible to write a new @InjectAll annotation to enable this simplification in code:

before, annotating individually each field:

```
@Inject
private Logger logger;

@Inject
private Event<String> simpleMessageEvent;
```

after, grouping all injected fields in one group:

```
@InjectAll {
   private Logger logger;
   private Event<String> simpleMessageEvent;
}
```

or any equivalent syntax which allows me to write more compact code?

Comment: Hehe, I find lists like yours in my code too... and for me it a smell that the bean is *breaking the single responsibility principle* and is in need of refactoring/rethinking. What you ask *can be done* (CDI extension-not with the suggested syntax). But I believe that it *should not* be done.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposal includes two Java syntax errors:

- You can't group field declarations in a block.
- You can't annotate blocks.

You might be able to create a CDI extension to support something like

```
@InjectAll({"logger", "simpleMessageEvent"})
public class MyClass {
    private Logger logger;
    private Event<String> simpleMessageEvent;    
}
```

but this is not really less verbose than having the `@Inject` annotation directly on the fields.

Comment: sure, my code was not "pure Java", just a proposition to improve Java and annotation syntax. Java is not set in stone and probably in future it will be possible to extend/customize the language syntax to accommodate special needs. Thanks for the input anyway... but using strings to refer to fields would break upon renaming fields..

Answer (score 0):

In CDI there is no built-in way to achieve this.
As was mentioned, you can use CDI extension combined with your imagination to create a custom syntax which will do just what you want. However, this will not make things much simpler and might just add on to complexity and lessen readability of code.

I'd rather suggest you go through your code again and see if you truly need that many injections in each class or if, perhaps, you need to refactor that class into several others to divide the per-class responsibility evenly. What you describe is often a case of "uber entry classes" which handle pretty much everything - that, of course, is not the best of practices.